# How to add fixed banner that pushes all other data down?

Tags: html, css

I am looking to add a header to my webpage for a current campaign. I have the code up until this point but it covers my logo and the other header when I add it in. How do I fix this so that it pushes the rest of the page down?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
 * {
   margin: 0; 
   padding: 0;
 }

 div#banner { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 0; 
   left: 0; 
   background-color: #00AD83; 
   width: 100%; 
 }
 div#banner-content { 
   width: 200px; 
   margin: 0 auto; 
   padding: 10px; 
   border: 1px solid #000;
 }
 div#main-content { 
   padding-top: 70px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="banner">
<div id="banner-content">
Banner content will go here
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a top margin to the content that follows:

```
#banner + * {
  margin-top: 70px; /* or whatever the banner's actual height is  */
}
```